# Connecting to WiFi using TP-LINK WN-722N V2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, wpa-supplicant, tp-link

I recently bought a TP-LINK WN-722N V2 wifi adapter and I want to connect to a WiFi network.

I installed drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu according to readme file. Then I tried using wpa_supplicant, but I get the following error:

```
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets: {}
  version: 2
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlxd0374595198d:
      access-points:
        "WLAN3":
          password: "my-password"
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

When I run `sudo netplan apply` the following warning is displayed (2 times), even after executing the suggested command:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of netplan-wpa-wlxd0374595198d.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect with wpa_supplicant? Why not netplan? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I am a beginner and I didn't even know about netplan. I just want to make any connection for now and wpa_supplicant seems pretty simple.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: "Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units."  Did you? `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` followed by: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply`

Comment: I still get the warning even after running these commands.